# Implementing a UITableView and it's Controller

Tags: xcode, controller, uitableview

I am trying to implement programmatically a UITableView.

I have a UIView (named IndexView). Here is the constructor :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        MyTableViewController* favorite_table_view_controller = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
        UITableView* theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 65, 280, 350) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        theTableView.delegate = favorite_table_view_controller;
        theTableView.dataSource = favorite_table_view_controller;
        [self addSubview:theTableView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

MyTableViewController is defined this way :

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

And implements the two necessary functions :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return data.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

And I get this error :

```
[__NSMallocBlock__ tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6897de0
2012-07-18 12:07:24.607 ButtonsTest[22854:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6897de0'
```

I think there is a problem when I'm binding the controller to the view. But I can't find where.

Any idea where does the problem come from ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not construct your viewcontroller from a view. It should be done the other way around.(construct views from UIVIewControllers)

make a ViewController that subclasses `UIViewController` and then let it implement the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. If you still need to control the UITableView from a another controller class setup this connection in the parent `UIViewController`, never from the View itself. That is the basic premise of the MVC used intensively in iOS

Comment: Yep, you can see it on the first block

Comment: I'm trying to do it without the interface builder. And my controller doesn't implement UITableViewController but UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> so I don't have any self.tableView.

Comment: ah Yes. Sorry. There seems to be some mistmatch in your code MyTableViewController looks like is called FavoriteTableViewController ? also it seems like you have more than one ViewController to control your UITableView?

Comment: OK. Thanks for the edit. I think you misunderstand how the framework should be used. I'm editing my answer above. Stay tuned :-)

Comment: Yes, it's because I change the name while writing the post. I edit my first post with the good name.

Comment: "I think you misunderstand how the framework" - I just don't like using Graphic Interface to build application. I prefer to do it programmatically. I think it doesn't matter, I'm sure there is a way to do it without Interface builder.

Comment: Yes. You can easily do it programatically. The intertfacebuilder is prety annoying, but it is important to construct the Controllers and views correctly

Comment: "it is important to construct the Controllers and views correctly" what's wrong with mine ?

Comment: You construct a UIViewController from within a view. I would strongly suggest that you try to add a new file to your project and specify it should subclass UITableViewController, and try implementing your logic there. It will be setup for your needs already

Comment: You should always try to use the framework as it is intended. This is not just a matter of writing clear and concise code. Your code above is leaking if your are managing mem yourself or are crashing miserably if you use ARC